# Solving a system of complex non-linear equations

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

I have a set of five equations which can be described as follows:

$m_{i}=\frac{k_{1}}{(x+a)^{i}} + \frac{k_{2}}{(b+d)^{i}}+ \frac{k_{3}}{c^{i}}$

for i=1 to 5 where 
$$\eqalign{
k_{1}&=\frac{a(x+a-b-c-d)+c(b+d)-xd}{(x+a-b-d)(x+a-c)} \\ 
}$$
$$\eqalign{
k_{2}&=\frac{x(d-c)}{(x+a-b-d)(b+d-c)} \\
}$$
$$\eqalign{
k_{3}&=\frac{xb}{(b+d-c)(x+a-c)}
}$$

$m_{i}$, $i$=1 to 5 are constants and $x,a,b,c,d$ are variables.

I want to find $x,a,b,c,d$ satisfying these equations.

Comment: This looks like a hard question, unless the symmetry makes it obvious or something already well-studied.  To help people trying to help with this, it might help to know: Where do these equations come from and what do you need the answer for?  Do you have actual numbers for the m_i, or do you want parametric solutions in terms of them?  If you have actual numbers, is a numerical approximation to the solutions (say from a homotopy continuation method) sufficient?  Do you want all the solutions or just one?  Do you know anything about Groebner basis methods?  How good a computer do you have?